# Can I designate admin accounts in the developer console for which I can check from within GAE Endpoints API impl?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to have some restrictions on my endpoints API where even if a user is authenticated, they might not be allowed to perform certain actions. I'm mostly guarding against someone being malicious and writing their own client against my backend (my own client will never do what I'm guarding against).

However, I'd still like to be able to perform those actions as myself for debugging purposes.

A simple approach would be to hardcode some "admin" email addresses on the backend.

Is there a better way? Ideally, I'd want to be able to specify the list in the console, and then in code I could have some API on the google User class such as user.isAdmin().

Does such a thing exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using endpoints, you have the opportunity to include a User object parameter in java or use `from google.appengine.api import users` in python and then `user.get_current_user()`. If the user is administrator, you can check this ([python example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers)) ([javadoc for function isUserAdmin()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService#isUserAdmin())). Do this inside your protected API functions.

[You can read more about authorization in endpoints here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth). In general the docs are a great place to find this kind of info.

Comment: Thanks i actually found the isUserAdmin a while ago but forgot to update. Im a java developer and i didn't see any mention of it in our docs (and ive spent a lot of time on authorization, took a bit to iron out stuff). Ill mark you reply as the answer though, thanks a lot for taking the time.

Comment: Thanks for the good SO etiquette in terms of getting back to the thread anyway, explaining what you did, and marking an answer :) peace